# How to remove special characters from with in a column of a csv file in java

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

My CSV file looks like this :

I want to parse the following CSV file :

```
Entity,GeographicLocation(Headers)
coffee service,"San Antonio, TX Metro"
coffee service,"Honolulu, HI Metro"
coffee service,"Little Rock, AR Metro"
coffee service,"Jacksonville, FL Metro"
coffee service,"Lincoln, NE Metro"
```

I want to get the fields of this form :(desired Output)

```
coffee+service,San+Antonio+TX+Metro
coffee+service,Honolulu+HI+Metro
coffee+service,Little+Rock+AR+Metro and so on ...
```

My code looks like this :

```
     // String CSVfilename = args[0];
    String csvfile="/Users/cdas/databaseprograms/coffeeservice.csv";

     // Step 1 >
     // code to read the data from the CSV file
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
    StringTokenizer st=null;
    String line="";
     int linenumber=0;
     int columnnumber;
    int free=0;
    int free1=0;

 // create the arraylist
  ArrayList<String> Typeof = new ArrayList<String>();
  // ArrayList for the adgroupId
  ArrayList<String> Where = new ArrayList<String>();

   // reading from the CSV file
   while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    linenumber++;
    columnnumber=0;

      st=new StringTokenizer(line,",");
      while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            columnnumber++;
            String token=st.nextToken();
            token = token.replaceAll("\"","");
            token = token.replaceAll(",","");
            System.out.println(token);
            if("Entity".equals(token)){
                    free=columnnumber;
                    System.out.println("the value of free"+free);
                    } else if("GeographicLocation".equals(token)){
                    free1=columnnumber;
                    System.out.println("the value of free1"+free1);
                    }
            if(linenumber>1){
                if (columnnumber==free){                    
                    token = token.replaceAll(" ","+");
                        Typeof.add(token);
                    } else if(columnnumber==free1){
                    //token = token.replaceAll(",","+");
                    token = token.replaceAll(" ","+");
                        Where.add(token);
                        }
    }                   
 }
 }

 // converting the  headline arraylist to array
  String[] entity=Typeof.toArray(new String[Typeof.size()]);
   for(int i=0;i<entity.length;i++){
        System.out.println(entity[i]);}

        // converting the keyword Id arraylist to array
        String[] whereof=Where.toArray(new String[Where.size()]);
        for(int i=0;i<whereof.length;i++){
        System.out.println(whereof[i]);
        }


 My Output is like : -
  Entity
the value of free1
GeographicLocation
the value of free12
coffee service
San Antonio
TX Metro
coffee service
Honolulu
HI Metro
coffee service
Little Rock
AR Metro
coffee service
Jacksonville
FL Metro
coffee service
Lincoln
NE Metro
```

I have succeeded in replacing the double quotes but the bufferedReader is escaping at the comma which I do not Want. Please help me with the following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String str = "coffee service,\"San Antonio, TX Metro\"";
    System.out.println("str = " + str.replaceAll("\"","")
                                     .replaceAll(", "," ")
                                     .replaceAll(" ","+"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
str = coffee+service,San+Antonio+TX+Metro
```

Comment: How will I get str at the first place? please possible improve on your answer.

Comment: @user2602860 you have it in `line` since you're doing: `while((line=br.readLine())!=null){...`